# Wrong encoding when getting metadata form image with exif_read_data

Tags: php, html, encoding

I'm getting the 'Comments' information from a uploaded image with the exif_read_data function.
I want to insert this information into the corresponding image 'alt' tag. The inserted value looks like this:
T�r�a�v�e�l���

I tried several encoding variants but i can't get a proper string.

PHP:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($dir.$image , 0 ,true);
$rel  = $exif["IFD0"]["Comments"];
```

HTML:

```
<img alt='$rel' src='test.jpg' />
```

OUTPUT:
something like this...

```
<img alt='T�r�a�v�e�l��� ' src='test.jpg' />
```

The actual encoding for the html page is UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Not sure, but this looks like it may be UTF-16 encoded...

Comment: Try `mb_detect_encoding` and converting to UTF-8 with the result of that.

Comment: I tried the mb_detect_encoding and converting to UTF-8 and the result looked like that: 'Travel�'. So far i'd found a solution just a workaround.

Comment: Workaround: $rel = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $rel);

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if will solve your problem (if yes, let me know here). But there's a comment at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exif-read-data.php) with a php.ini config to set the exif encoding:

```
<?php
ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: apparently if you set the exif comments/description fields in Windows the encoding will be automatically set to ASCII (you can check this with detect_encoding, as suggested in the comments). As ASCII is a subset of utf8 you can just use:

```
$rel  = utf8_encode($exif["IFD0"]["Comments"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is: `$exif = $exif['WINXP']['Comments'];`